# Logon Credentials for SQLServer Service

Tags: sql, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple question that I am not familiar with so please understand. Is the password in the service(SQLServer) the same with the one I use to login in with JDBC or is it a different thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the credentials are the same but if your remove the password in service(SQLServer) LogOn it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. The password used for the service is (read: should be) different than the login credentials.

The service account is the windows or AD account which is used to run SQL server. The permissions you set should be the lowest possible.

In order to login and connect to a SQL database, you are going to need a login. This can be either a SQL login or Windows Authenticated.

Now, it's entirely possible that a windows authenticated login was created which uses the same account as the service account, but that's not good practice.

Ideally, you would have a separate login to the server, which is what you would use for your JDBC connection. You would need the login to connect, and that user would also need to be mapped to the database that you are connecting to.

Since I don't know the specifics of your environment, I can't answer the question directly.